# Meteor/Iron Router Reactivity Infinite Loop

Tags: meteor, infinite-loop, iron-router

So I have a route that upon rendering I update the document that's also being used to render data on the page.

But, when I modify that data via onRun I get an infinite loop. :(
Doing this in the data function doesn't solve the issue as that method is reactive as well, as it seems all of the methods I can use (onAfterAction, onBeforeAction, etc). onBeforeAction would be perfect if I could use it...

```
ViewRoomController = RouteController.extend({
    data: function() {
        return Rooms.findOne(this.params._id);
    },
    onRun: function() {
        var room = Rooms.findOne(this.params._id),
            that = this,
            messages;

        if(room !== undefined) {
            messages = room.messages;

            //Do stuff with messages...
            //This will go into an infinite loop.
            //setTimeout is here just so loop doesn't lock up process.

            setTimeout(function() {
                Rooms.update(
                    that.params._id, {
                        $set: {
                            messages: messages
                        }
                    }
                );
            }, 1);
        }
    }
});
```

I bet I'm missing something silly, but I've been stuck on this for over an hour now... :)

Comment: I've also tried changing onRun to 'action' and then calling render() - causes the loop as well.

Obviously I could just not make the function in data not return the DB object but I want the data on the page to be reactive.

Comment: Could you try making your `data` function return `{_id: this.params._id}`, and then wrap your template with `{{#with theRoom}}...{{/with}}` where `theRoom` is a helper returning `Rooms.findOne(this._id)`? Then when the room changes, the template will re-render, but Iron-Router won't re-run the route. I don't know if that's desirable.

Answer (score 0):

I found the correct way to do this was to just pass the ID to the template and then have the template itself be reactive and not the entire route.

The more you know. :)